# Should throw all Parsing error at a time :Parse un well formed XML

Tags: xml, parsing, exception, xml-parsing, throw

To check all nodes in xml are Well formed or not. 
I am trying to throw all missing & wrong format in xml but it throws exception for single node which is missing.

I need to **throw all missing nodes & not well formed nodes in xml** at a time.
Thanks in advance.

```
/**
     * To Validate the XML with its Schema
     * @param xmlPath
     * @param schemaXSDPath
     * @return 
     */
    public static boolean validateXMLagainstSchema(String xmlPath,String schemaXSDPath)
    {
        try 
        {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setValidating(true);
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            SAXParser parser = null;
            try 
            {
                parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            } 
            catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            catch (SAXException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
                    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

            parser.setProperty(
                    "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource",
                     schemaXSDPath);
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(parser.getXMLReader());
            InputSource ip=new InputSource(xmlPath);
            reader.read(ip);  
      } 
        catch (SAXNotRecognizedException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        catch (SAXNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        catch (SAXParseException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        catch (SAXException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        catch (DocumentException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally XML parsers are not particularly good at reporting multiple well-formedness errors. You might find a parser that does it, but I don't think Xerces does. In general recovery from errors such as a "<" in content or an omitted closing quote in an attribute value is rather difficult; it's hard to find places where one can reliably resume the parsing without the risk of generating reams of spurious errors.